# How to write one file in two different methods in python

Tags: python, file, methods

I'm trying to write just one file in two different methods.

Is there anyway I can do it without creating another save method?

Comment: Pass the open file to both methods?

Comment: I'm using with open(file,'w')as f: and it won't let me write when it comes to second method.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
def method1(f):
   f.write("something")

def method2(f):
   f.write("something else")

with open("myfile", "w") as f:
    method1(f)
    method2(f)
```